# What namespace do the following angularJS declarations belong to?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to angularJS.

When I declare a var or a function inside an angularJS directive, what namespace do aFunction() and aVar belong to?

Is it correct to declare them in this way or should I prefix them with, say, $scope?

Here is a code snippet:

```
define(['aName'], function () {'use strict';       
   angular.module('aName').directive('aName', ['$compile', 'serviceName',  
     '$parse', '$window', '$document', function ($compile, serviceName, $parse, 
        myWindow, $document) { return {

           ...

           function aFunction() { ... } //or should it be $scope.aFunction?

           var aVar = function anotherFunction() { ... } //or should it be $scope.aVar?

           ...

        };
   }]);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespacing in angularjs isn't the strongest part. Things eventually go to an object called `angular`. There are several functions defined there that you can use to create your objects, like `module`. This is specially problematic with [service names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909474/namespacing-services-in-angularjs)(we rely on dependency injection using the name of the service) or global function controllers.
A module is a logical group of, for example, directives or controllers but (not really sure about this) it is not a way to isolate components. try having [a directive with the same name in two modules](http://jsfiddle.net/wYLUM/1/).
In the tutorial they define controllers as global functions:

```
function MainCtrl() {...}
```

instead of using modules to, at least, not pollute the global namespace.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
```

angular.directive() returns a DDO (directive definition object), like:

```
app.directive('person', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: '<div class="person">Person name: {{ name }}</div>',
    scope: {
        name: '@'
    }
};
});
```

There is a limited set of properties that you should be using (restrict, replace, template, templateUrl...).

having `function aFunction() { ... }` there doesn't make much sense. it's not even `key:value`.
If it's a function that encapsualtes some logic in your directive but doesn't have to be exposed to the view, you can have it as follows:

```
app.directive('person', function () {
var f = function() {...};
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: '<div class="person">Person name: {{ name }}</div>',
    link: function(...) { 
        /* and it becomes available */
        f()
     }
};
});
```

if you don't use `var` , it'll try to resolve it as a global object following the javascript scope rules.

Your second example `var aVar = function anotherFunction() { ... }` is a function only available in the current [javascript] scope, that is, in whatever function you had it. for example:

```
link: function(...) { 
   /* and it becomes available */
   f();
   var g = function () {...};
   g(); // only works in the scope of link();
}
```

If what you want is to expose this function to the view, for something like `<div ng-click="fireFn()">` you should probably have it in the scope. A good place to define this function in the scope would be a controller or the link function:
in a controller,

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'World';
    $scope.fireFn = function() {...}; // scope is the injected service. use the $
});
```

in the linker:

```
link: function(scope) { 
   /* and it becomes available */
   f();
   var g = function () {...};
   g(); // only works in the javascript scope (not the parameter!) of link();
   scope.fireFn = function() {...}; // scope is the first parameter
}
```

As regarding to isolating modules, putting them in closures can't cause any harm:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var mymodule = angular.module('mymodule', []);
}());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Eduard for your very comprehensive and useful answer