# AngularJS access a service in a module when there is no direct dependency

Tags: angularjs

I've been trying to optimise how I manage modules in a reasonable sized App and have come across a possible issue with dependencies.

As far as I can tell a module can access a service in another module even if there is no direct dependency.

Say we have an `app` module that depends on two modules `moduleA` and `moduleB`. Is it correct that `moduleB` should be able to access the dependencies of `moduleA`? This is what appears to happen in the fiddle I set up - https://jsfiddle.net/neridum/jfdsjhjo/

To me this means that you could have the issue that if `moduleA` was altered it could affect `moduleB` even though the two are not dependencies.

I may have gone about it the wrong way or have misunderstood something. Or it could be a limitation of the Angular module system.

Edit: There is a similar module issue in Angular regarding the naming collision - ["Namespacing" services in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909474) I think this is a slightly different issue as in addition to the naming collision there is also the issue of modules being available when they perhaps shouldn't be.

Comment: How would you know to use `SubModuleFactory` in `moduleB`?  Theoretically modules should be developed somewhat separately from one another.

Comment: @ExplosionPills What if Modules A and B just happened to depend on factories with the same name in different modules? [Example showing that the system is broken](https://jsfiddle.net/ehqn318m/). This behavior of the module system seems quite bizarre and sloppy. It's essentially backflow through the dependency chain.

Comment: @ExplosionPills Rationally speaking, including two modules as dependencies in a third module should not cause them to pool their dependencies together (and possibly overwrite each other), but apparently that is what actually happens.

Comment: You could consider this a bug.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909474/namespacing-services-in-angularjs

Comment: @ExplosionPills Thanks for the link. I think this question could be treated as a duplicate of that one. To OP: Yes, as the answers to the other questions state, it's true that names on services, etc. are all pooled together within a dependency network, and if you have a reason to believe that could become an issue, the suggested solution is to use a prefix on the names of your services, to namespace them.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I think this is a slightly different issue although it is related to the namespacing problem. The use case here is that I have a utility module that several other modules can depend on. It would be too easy to forget a dependency which would be a problem if the module that was declaring the dependency was removed.

Answer (score 0):

Both modules should act independently , There should not be any necessity to access  the others dependencies.

Comment: No, they should not need to access each others' dependencies, but Angular makes it so that they _can_ access each others' dependencies (and even overwrite them). That is the problem.

Comment: Yes, the issue I have is that one of the dependencies is a util service which I wanted to modularise better. It has methods that are used in several different modules which is what brought me to my issue. Currently it is a service on the main module.