# How to reference values with the same name from different modules

Tags: angularjs

If I have some modules which defines the same `value` object:

```
var m1 = angular.module('m1', []);
m1.value('test', 'AAA');

var m2 = angular.module('m2', []);
m2.value('test', 'BBB');
```

Notice `m1` and `m2` both have the same value `test`.

Then in the main module, I depend on them two:

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', ['m1','m2']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, test) {
  $scope.test = test;
});
```

And the HTML is very simple:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
 [{{test}}]
</body>
```

It will show`[BBB]` in the final page. I can see that the value `test` of `m1` has been overrode by the one of `m2`.

You can see a live demo here: http://plnkr.co/edit/u7u8p0nYqq9CvNxWKv5G?p=preview

Is there any way to show the values of `test` both from `m1` and `m2` in the same page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modules and name clashes in Angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13406791/modules-and-name-clashes-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In short - **no**. AngularJS modules form one namespace. If you define 2 values with the same name on 2 different modules only one will be visible during runtime. This applies to any providers, not only values.

This might get addressed in future versions of AngularJS but for now **your best option is to prefix your values (and other providers) with a module name**.

Comment: @Freewind I'm afraid that there is no other option at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you *can* (sort of) do this, but it requires a bit more manual work. [See this plunkr.](http://plnkr.co/edit/gSBuraEytj8XXwLK8dgd)

```
var foo = angular.module('foo', ['ng']).value('test', 1);
var bar = angular.module('bar', ['foo']).value('test', 2);
console.log(angular.injector(['foo']).get('test')); // 1
bar.service('original', ['test', function(test) {
    console.log(test); // 2
}]);
```

As the other answers stated, the module namespace is global so the controller in 'foo' gets the Test value from 'bar'. However, by using angular.injector([...modules]) we can explicitly retrieve values/services/whatnot from certain modules.

Of course this doesn't natively work with Angular's DI system, but personally that doesn't really bother me since function(Foo) {} or function() { Foo = angular.injector(['myModule']).get('Foo'); } is slightly more typing, but not necessarily worse (we're still injecting something, only manually).

Also, directives and filters would need to be made unique in another way, but it gives a starting point.