# How to use two AngularJS services with same name from different modules?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-module

Supposed I have two modules for AngularJS, e.g. `foo` and `bar`, and both of them define a service called `baz`.

In my application I depend on them by saying:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [ 'foo', 'bar' ]);
```

Then I can try to use the `baz` service in a controller by using

```
app.controller('blaController', [ '$scope', 'baz', function($scope, baz) {
  // ...
}]);
```

How can I define which of the two services I'd like to use? Is there something such as a fully-qualified name?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reference values with the same name from different modules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15342657/how-to-reference-values-with-the-same-name-from-different-modules)

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Namespacing" services in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909474/namespacing-services-in-angularjs)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modules and name clashes in Angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13406791/modules-and-name-clashes-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The service locator looks services up by name ([angularjs guide DI](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)). However ["Namespacing" services in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909474/namespacing-services-in-angularjs):

> As of today AngularJS doesn't handle namespace collisions for services
>   so if you've got 2 different modules with the service named the same
>   way and you include both modules in your app, only one service will be
>   available.

I guess you can make the fully qualified name "by hand": name the service `foo.baz` and `bar.baz` instead of plain `baz`. It's kind of a self-delusion. Moreover, writing it this way doesn't make namespacing real, but another person that reads the code might think so.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you can mitigate this with closures `(function() { module declaration}());`

Answer (score 0):

When we have two services with the same name, you have to differentiate them while using it in your local module. Let's see some code below to understand how it works,

I have two Util services and need to differentiate them,

```
angular
  .module('module1', [
  ])
  .service('UtilService', UtilService)
  .service('another.UtilService', UtilService)
  .name;
```

In the controller file, you can simply inject like below.

```
export class Controller {
  public static $inject: string[] = ['UtilService', 'another.UtilService'];

constructor(
    private utilService: UtilService,
    private anotherUtilService
  ) {
     console.log(this.utilService) // will print the main util service methods
     console.log(this.anotherUtilService) // will print the another util service 
     methods
  }
```