# AngularJS Multiple ng-app within a page

Tags: angularjs

I have just started learning Angular JS and created some basic samples however I am stuck with the following problem.

I have created 2 modules and 2 controllers.

```
shoppingCart -> ShoppingCartController
namesList -> NamesController
```

There are associated views for each controller. The first View renders fine but second is not rendering. There are no errors.

http://jsfiddle.net/ep2sQ/

Please help me solve this issue.

Also is there any possibility to add console in View to check what values are passed from Controller.

e.g. in the following div can we add console.log and output the controller values

```
<div ng-app="shoppingCart" ng-controller="ShoppingCartController">
</div>
```

Comment: may be this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860595/how-to-define-two-angular-apps-modules-in-one-page

Comment: Thank you Cherniv. This is very helpful and I solved the problem using the link you provided. Please could you also provide info on how to use console.log to dump Controller within View/Template

    {{console.log}}

is not working.

Comment: you welcome. note that you already doing "console" in a views , this: `{{item.product_name}}` actually "prints" a value from your model

Comment: Is there anything wrong with creating multiple apps for a webapp?
I have this project where each html page has it's own app, I want to know if performance will be impacted in anyway?

Comment: While it's possible to bootstrap more than one AngularJS application per page, we don't actively test against this scenario. It's possible that you'll run into problems, especially with complex apps, so caution is advised. See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Bootstrap](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap).

Answer (score 194, accepted):

So basically as  mentioned by Cherniv we need to bootstrap the modules to have multiple ng-app within the same page. Many thanks for all the inputs.

```js
var shoppingCartModule = angular.module("shoppingCart", [])
shoppingCartModule.controller("ShoppingCartController",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
      product_name: "Product 1",
      price: 50
    }, {
      product_name: "Product 2",
      price: 20
    }, {
      product_name: "Product 3",
      price: 180
    }];
    $scope.remove = function(index) {
      $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
);
var namesModule = angular.module("namesList", [])
namesModule.controller("NamesController",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [{
      username: "Nitin"
    }, {
      username: "Mukesh"
    }];
  }
);
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("App2"), ['namesList']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>

<div id="App1" ng-app="shoppingCart" ng-controller="ShoppingCartController">
  <h1>Your order</h1>
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <span>{{item.product_name}}</span>
    <span>{{item.price | currency}}</span>
    <button ng-click="remove($index);">Remove</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="App2" ng-app="namesList" ng-controller="NamesController">
  <h1>List of Names</h1>
  <div ng-repeat="_name in names">
    <p>{{_name.username}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can create a directive to do this instead http://stackoverflow.com/a/22898036/984780

Comment: The angular documentation says that when manually bootstrapping an app, NOT to use the ngApp directive.  So ng-app="namesList" (could/should) be reoved.  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap

Comment: For those who have ng-app's in a two seperate js files the below code might help  
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("App2"), ['namesList']);
});

Comment: Note : in my app, i had to put this line "angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("App2"), ['namesList']);" in $(document).ready function

Comment: It is not working for me.Only the first ng-app works correctly

Comment: La masse where u put  "angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("App2"), In java script file or angular js file.Need more depth plz

Answer (score 121):

#### To run multiple applications in an HTML document you must manually bootstrap them using [angular.bootstrap()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap)

#### HTML

```
<!-- Automatic Initialization -->
<div ng-app="myFirstModule">
    ...
</div>
<!-- Need To Manually Bootstrap All Other Modules -->
<div id="module2">
    ...
</div>
```

#### JS

```
angular.
  bootstrap(document.getElementById("module2"), ['mySecondModule']);
```

---

The reason for this is that only one AngularJS application can be automatically bootstrapped per HTML document. The first `ng-app` found in the document will be used to define the root element to auto-bootstrap as an application.

In other words, while it is technically possible to have several applications per page, only one ng-app directive will be automatically instantiated and initialized by the Angular framework.

Comment: Only one `ngApp` directive can be *auto-bootloaded* per HTML Document but you can have multiple apps as long as you manually bootstrap the subsequent ones.

Comment: @CodeHater where is `namesList` module located then? Could you please update your answer, so that it would be clearer?

Comment: This is wrong. You CAN have multiple ng-app. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24867989/753632

Comment: @AndroidDev, I don't follow. The link you reference does not show multiple ng-app attributes.

Answer (score 42):

*You can use `angular.bootstrap()` directly...* the problem is you lose the benefits of directives.

First you need to get a reference to the HTML element in order to bootstrap it, which means your code is now coupled to your HTML.

Secondly the association between the two is not as apparent. With `ngApp` you can clearly see what HTML is associated with what module and you know where to look for that information. But `angular.bootstrap()` could be invoked from anywhere in your code.

If you are going to do it at all the best way would be by using a directive. Which is what I did. It's called `ngModule`. Here is what your code would look like using it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="angular.js"></script>
        <script src="angular.ng-modules.js"></script>
        <script>
          var moduleA = angular.module("MyModuleA", []);
          moduleA.controller("MyControllerA", function($scope) {
              $scope.name = "Bob A";
          });

          var moduleB = angular.module("MyModuleB", []);
          moduleB.controller("MyControllerB", function($scope) {
              $scope.name = "Steve B";
          });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-modules="MyModuleA, MyModuleB">
            <h1>Module A, B</h1>
            <div ng-controller="MyControllerA">
                {{name}}
            </div>
            <div ng-controller="MyControllerB">
                {{name}}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div ng-module="MyModuleB">
            <h1>Just Module B</h1>
            <div ng-controller="MyControllerB">
                {{name}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can get the source code for it at:

http://www.simplygoodcode.com/2014/04/angularjs-getting-around-ngapp-limitations-with-ngmodule/

It's implemented in the same way as `ngApp`. It simply calls `angular.bootstrap()` behind the scenes.

Answer (score 9):

In my case I had to wrap the bootstrapping of my second app in `angular.element(document).ready` for it to work:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("app2"), ["app2"]);
});
```

Comment: **V1.6 Deprecated:**  Use `angular.element(callback)` instead of `angular.element(document).ready(callback))`. See [AngularJS angular.element API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element). Also https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/369fb7f4f73664bcdab0350701552d8bef6f605e

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example of two applications in one html page and two conrollers in one application :

```
    <div ng-app = "myapp">
      <div  ng-controller = "C1" id="D1">
         <h2>controller 1 in app 1 <span id="titre">{{s1.title}}</span> !</h2>
      </div>

      <div  ng-controller = "C2" id="D2">
         <h2>controller 2 in app 1 <span id="titre">{{s2.valeur}}</span> !</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var A1 = angular.module("myapp", [])

        A1.controller("C1", function($scope) {
            $scope.s1 = {};
            $scope.s1.title = "Titre 1";
         });

        A1.controller("C2", function($scope) {
            $scope.s2 = {};
            $scope.s2.valeur = "Valeur 2";
         });
    </script>

    <div ng-app="toapp" ng-controller="C1" id="App2">
        <br>controller 1 in app 2
        <br>First Name: <input type = "text" ng-model = "student.firstName">
        <br>Last Name : <input type="text" ng-model="student.lastName">
        <br>Hello : {{student.fullName()}}
        <br>
    </div>

    <script>
        var A2 = angular.module("toapp", []);
        A2.controller("C1", function($scope) {
            $scope.student={
                firstName:"M",
                lastName:"E",
                fullName:function(){
                    var so=$scope.student;
                    return so.firstName+" "+so.lastName;
                }
            };
        });
        angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("App2"), ['toapp']);
    </script>
<style>
    #titre{color:red;}
    #D1{ background-color:gray; width:50%; height:20%;}
    #D2{ background-color:yellow; width:50%; height:20%;}
    input{ font-weight: bold; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can merge multiple modules in one rootModule , and assign that module as 
ng-app to a superior element ex: body tag.

code ex:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="namesController.js"></script>
<script src="myController.js"></script>
<script>var rootApp = angular.module('rootApp', ['myApp1','myApp2'])</script>
<body ng-app="rootApp">

<div ng-app="myApp1" ng-controller="myCtrl" >
First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
</div>

<div ng-app="myApp2" ng-controller="namesCtrl">
<ul>
  <li ng-bind="first">{{first}}
  </li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are nesting two different apps inside the rootApp, Angular does not allow nesting of apps

Answer (score 4):

```js
         var shoppingCartModule = angular.module("shoppingCart", [])
          shoppingCartModule.controller("ShoppingCartController",
           function($scope) {
             $scope.items = [{
               product_name: "Product 1",
               price: 50
             }, {
               product_name: "Product 2",
               price: 20
             }, {
               product_name: "Product 3",
               price: 180
             }];
             $scope.remove = function(index) {
               $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
             }
           }
         );
         var namesModule = angular.module("namesList", [])
          namesModule.controller("NamesController",
           function($scope) {
             $scope.names = [{
               username: "Nitin"
             }, {
               username: "Mukesh"
             }];
           }
         );


         var namesModule = angular.module("namesList2", [])
          namesModule.controller("NamesController",
           function($scope) {
             $scope.names = [{
               username: "Nitin"
             }, {
               username: "Mukesh"
             }];
           }
         );


         angular.element(document).ready(function() {
           angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("App2"), ['namesList']);
           angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("App3"), ['namesList2']);
         });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="App1" ng-app="shoppingCart" ng-controller="ShoppingCartController">
    <h1>Your order</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      <span>{{item.product_name}}</span>
      <span>{{item.price | currency}}</span>
      <button ng-click="remove($index);">Remove</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="App2" ng-app="namesList" ng-controller="NamesController">
    <h1>List of Names</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="_name in names">
      <p>{{_name.username}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="App3" ng-app="namesList2" ng-controller="NamesController">
    <h1>List of Names</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="_name in names">
      <p>{{_name.username}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just an extension to have multiple ng-app's in a single page I had to just combine both saeb-amini and @Nithin Mukesh code -- Thank you  both

Comment: This concept is working for me. angular.element(document).ready(function() {
           angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("App2"), ['namesList']);
           angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("App3"), ['namesList2']);
         });

Answer (score 3):

```js
// root-app
const rootApp = angular.module('root-app', ['app1', 'app2E']);

// app1
const app11aa = angular.module('app1', []);
app11aa.controller('main', function($scope) {
  $scope.msg = 'App 1';
});

// app2
const app2 = angular.module('app2E', []);
app2.controller('mainB', function($scope) {
  $scope.msg = 'App 2';
});

// bootstrap
angular.bootstrap(document.querySelector('#app1a'), ['app1']);
angular.bootstrap(document.querySelector('#app2b'), ['app2E']);
```

```html
<!-- angularjs@1.7.0 -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<!-- root-app -->
<div ng-app="root-app">

  <!-- app1 -->
  <div id="app1a">
    <div ng-controller="main">
      {{msg}}
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- app2 -->
  <div id="app2b">
    <div ng-controller="mainB">
      {{msg}}
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Only one app is automatically initialized. Others have to manually initialized as follows:

Syntax:

```
angular.bootstrap(element, [modules]);
```

Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.5.8" data-require="angular.js@1.5.8"></script>
  <script data-require="ui-router@0.2.18" data-semver="0.2.18" src="//cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-router/0.2.18/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script>
    var parentApp = angular.module('parentApp', [])
  .controller('MainParentCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'universe';
  });



var childApp = angular.module('childApp', ['parentApp'])
  .controller('MainChildCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'world';
  });


angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('childApp'), ['childApp']);
});
    
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="childApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainParentCtrl">
      Hello {{name}} !
      <div>
        <div ng-controller="MainChildCtrl">
          Hello {{name}} !
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[AngularJS API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap)

Answer (score 1):

**You can define a Root ng-App and in this ng-App you can define multiple nd-Controler. Like this**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>

<style>
         table, th , td {
            border: 1px solid grey;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 5px;
         }

         table tr:nth-child(odd) {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
         }

         table tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #ffffff;
         }
      </style>

     <script>
      var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);

      mainApp.controller('studentController1', function ($scope) {
      $scope.student = {
      firstName: "MUKESH",
      lastName: "Paswan",

      fullName: function () {
         var studentObject;
         studentObject = $scope.student;
         return studentObject.firstName + " " + studentObject.lastName;
                     }
                 };
             });

             mainApp.controller('studentController2', function ($scope) {
                 $scope.student = {
                     firstName: "Mahesh",
                     lastName: "Parashar",
                     fees: 500,

                     subjects: [
                        { name: 'Physics', marks: 70 },
                        { name: 'Chemistry', marks: 80 },
                        { name: 'Math', marks: 65 },
                        { name: 'English', marks: 75 },
                        { name: 'Hindi', marks: 67 }
                     ],

                     fullName: function () {
                         var studentObject;
                         studentObject = $scope.student;
                         return studentObject.firstName + " " + studentObject.lastName;
                     }
                 };
             });
          </script>

    <body>
    <div ng-app = "mainApp">
    <div id="dv1"  ng-controller = "studentController1">
    Enter first name: <input type = "text" ng-model = "student.firstName"><br/><br/> Enter last name: <input type = "text" ng-model = "student.lastName"><br/>
    <br/>
     You are entering: {{student.fullName()}}
    </div>

    <div id="dv2" ng-controller = "studentController2">
     <table border = "0">
                <tr>
                   <td>Enter first name:</td>
                   <td><input type = "text" ng-model = "student.firstName"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                   <td>Enter last name: </td>
                   <td>
                      <input type = "text" ng-model = "student.lastName">
                   </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                   <td>Name: </td>
                   <td>{{student.fullName()}}</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                   <td>Subject:</td>

                   <td>
                      <table>
                         <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>.
                            <th>Marks</th>
                         </tr>

                         <tr ng-repeat = "subject in student.subjects">
                            <td>{{ subject.name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ subject.marks }}</td>
                         </tr>

                      </table>
                   </td>

                </tr>
             </table>

          </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have modified your jsfiddle, can make top most module as rootModule for rest of the modules.
>   Below Modifications updated on your jsfiddle.

1. Second Module can injected in RootModule.
2. In Html second defined ng-app placed inside the Root ng-app.

`Updated JsFiddle:`
http://jsfiddle.net/ep2sQ/1011/

Comment: Any idea why this is only evaluating the first `ng-app`? https://jsfiddle.net/vwcbtzdg/

Comment: First only automatically initialized, other have to manually initialize

Answer (score 0):

Use `angular.bootstrap(element, [modules], [config])` to manually start up AngularJS application (for more information, see the [Bootstrap guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap)).

See the following example:

```js
// root-app
const rootApp = angular.module('root-app', ['app1', 'app2']);

// app1
const app1 = angular.module('app1', []);
app1.controller('main', function($scope) {
  $scope.msg = 'App 1';
});

// app2
const app2 = angular.module('app2', []);
app2.controller('main', function($scope) {
  $scope.msg = 'App 2';
});

// bootstrap
angular.bootstrap(document.querySelector('#app1'), ['app1']);
angular.bootstrap(document.querySelector('#app2'), ['app2']);
```

```html
<!-- angularjs@1.7.0 -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<!-- root-app -->
<div ng-app="root-app">

  <!-- app1 -->
  <div id="app1">
    <div ng-controller="main">
      {{msg}}
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- app2 -->
  <div id="app2">
    <div ng-controller="main">
      {{msg}}
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -5):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="shoppingCartParentModule" >
     <div ng-controller="ShoppingCartController">
        <h1>Your order</h1>
        <div ng-repeat="item in items">
            <span>{{item.product_name}}</span>
            <span>{{item.price | currency}}</span>
            <button ng-click="remove($index);">Remove</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="NamesController">
        <h1>List of Names</h1>
        <div ng-repeat="name in names">
            <p>{{name.username}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<script>
var shoppingCartModule = angular.module("shoppingCart", [])
            shoppingCartModule.controller("ShoppingCartController",
                function($scope) {
                    $scope.items = [
                        {product_name: "Product 1", price: 50},
                        {product_name: "Product 2", price: 20},
                        {product_name: "Product 3", price: 180}
                    ];
                    $scope.remove = function(index) {
                        $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
                    }
                }
            );
            var namesModule = angular.module("namesList", [])
            namesModule.controller("NamesController",
                function($scope) {
                    $scope.names = [
                        {username: "Nitin"},
                        {username: "Mukesh"}
                    ];
                }
            );
   angular.module("shoppingCartParentModule",["shoppingCart","namesList"])
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Add description to your answer what you have posted

Comment: Needs comments explaining whats' going on ! Nice try!