# Multiple ng-app directives on a page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to be able to use multiple ng-app="{angular.module}" directives on one page. I want to do this to make the bits of my app more modular. I figure, if I can create angular modules and plug several of them into one document, I could take those modules and plug them into other projects easily.

I have seen people say that you can only use one ng-app directive on your page... is this true? Is it most accurate to say, "one ng-app directive per view"?

I hope this is not the case, or if it is the case that there is still a best way to achieve a high degree of abstract modularity.

Here are my modules/apps and their controllers...

```
var searchModj = angular.module('searchModule', []);


var controllers = {};

controllers.SearchList = function ($scope){

    $scope.coworkers = [
            {name: 'Joe Bob', city: 'Ukrainia'},
            {name: 'Adam Blobnovski', city: 'Logan' },
            {name: 'Carlos Sanchez', city: 'Deerbushle'},   
            {name: 'Martin Kellerweller', city: 'Uptown'},
            {name: 'John Doe',  city: 'New York City'}
        ];
};

searchModj.controller(controllers);



var fruitModj = angular.module('fruiter', []);



controllers.SomeFruit = function ($scope) {

    $scope.fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'pear'];

};

fruitModj.controller(controllers);
```

Ok, now here is the relevant part of my markup...

```
<div ng-app="searchModule">

    <div ng-controller="SearchList">

        Name: 
        <br/>
        <input type="text" ng-model="name" /> 
        <br/>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="coworker in coworkers | filter:name">{{ coworker.name }} - {{ coworker.city }}</li>
        </ul>

        <p>You are searching for <em>{{ name }}</em></p>


    </div>


</div>

<div ng-app="fruiter">
    <div ng-controller="SomeFruit">

        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">{{ fruits }}</li>
        </ul>

    </div>

</div>
```

I think because it comes first in the document, my "searchModule" app works and the second app does not. When I comment out the first app, the second works. So it looks like I'm confirming my most unfortunate suspicions. Regardless... if this is the case, then what is the best approach I can bear in mind to make the functionality on my projects as modular as possible?

Comment: you only want one `ng-app` on a page, but you can insert your other modules as dependencies of the main `ng-app` module

Comment: You require only one `ng-app` in your application. If you want to decide your application module at run time you should use `angular.bootstrap`. Refer http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap for details.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you only want one `ng-app` on a page, but you can insert your other modules as dependencies of the main `ng-app` module.

```
var app=angular.module('myNgAppName', ['searchModule']);
```

This will expose any directives , controllers etc you have in your `'searchModule'`

Comment: This is the correct answer. Ideally, you should break up your app into multiple modules as per your requirements and inject those modules as dependencies into your app.

Answer (score 7):

The limitations of the `ngApp` directive is just that, limitations of the directive, not AngularJS itself. Angular allow you to associate modules with multiple elements in a page, it even allows you to associate more than one module with each element.

Referencing other modules from you module will work. Another approach that will work is using the `angular.bootstrap()` method. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18583329/984780

Finally you can create a directive that works like `ngApp` without it's limitations. It would work exactly the way it does in your markup code. That's what I did you can get the code here:

http://www.simplygoodcode.com/2014/04/angularjs-getting-around-ngapp-limitations-with-ngmodule/

The directive is called `ngModule`. Here's a code sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="angular.js"></script>
        <script src="angular.ng-modules.js"></script>
        <script>
          var moduleA = angular.module("MyModuleA", []);
          moduleA.controller("MyControllerA", function($scope) {
              $scope.name = "Bob A";
          });

          var moduleB = angular.module("MyModuleB", []);
          moduleB.controller("MyControllerB", function($scope) {
              $scope.name = "Steve B";
          });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-modules="MyModuleA, MyModuleB">
            <h1>Module A, B</h1>
            <div ng-controller="MyControllerA">
                {{name}}
            </div>
            <div ng-controller="MyControllerB">
                {{name}}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div ng-module="MyModuleB">
            <h1>Just Module B</h1>
            <div ng-controller="MyControllerB">
                {{name}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: another great post luis

Answer (score 4):

Yes you only want one ng-app per page, but you can create other modules and declare them as dependencies of your main app.

```
var app=angular.module('appModule'); //resuable module

var app=angular.module('myApp', ['appModule']); //in the HTML ng-app="myApp"
```

So you can put re-usable stuff in appModule and use it in other projects. For example, I like to put my routing logic (i.e. re-routing users depending on their access levels) in a module that I reuse in other projects.

Note: You might want to look into $provider http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.$provide if you want to use data from your re-usable ("appModule") module inside the config method of your ng-app ("myApp") module.