# How many ng-App can be declared in in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

```
How many ng-App attributes can be declared in in Angular JS? and under what circumstances?
```

As I know that ng-app is used for auto bootstrap for an Angular JS application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple ng-app directives on a page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666816/multiple-ng-app-directives-on-a-page)

Answer (score 11):

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngApp

> Only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML document. The first ngApp found in the document will be used to define the root element to auto-bootstrap as an application. To run multiple applications in an HTML document you must manually bootstrap them using angular.bootstrap instead. AngularJS applications cannot be nested within each other.

TL; DR: you can have more than one, but only the first will be bootstrapped.

This question is similar to:

- [How to define two angular apps / modules in one page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860595/how-to-define-two-angular-apps-modules-in-one-page)
- [Multiple ng-app directives on a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666816/multiple-ng-app-directives-on-a-page)
- [AngularJS Multiple ng-app within a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571301/angularjs-multiple-ng-app-within-a-page)

Answer (score 1):

Came across very interesting virtue of ng-app directive for angularjs version 1.2.x, we can have applications bootstrapped without specifying any module name.

By using `<html ng-app="">` in the HTML template & a script file that contains the controller as a function:

```
function TestController($scope) {
    $scope.customer = {
      name: 'Naomi',
      address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
    };
    $scope.cars = ['Audi', 'BMW', 'Merc'];
  }
```

[Demo link](http://plnkr.co/edit/7GdWNtJyYYgIOSa8WlSJ?p=info)