# It is a good idea create more than one ng-app in AngularJS application?

Tags: angularjs

I am planning to develop my company's CRM (Customer Relationship Management) system in AngularJS. This system is not small, there are modules like customer CRUD, Shopping Cart, After-Sales Service, and so on.

As I noticed, usually an AngularJS has just one main "ng-app".

1. Is there any problem to build more than on "ng-app" for a system (one for each CRM module)?
2. What would be its pros and cons?

Edit 1: I am not planning to use more than one ng-app per HTML, but many (about 7) in the whole application.

Edit 2: The idea is create one Angular Module for each CRM module, for example:

*customer.html*
`<html lang="en" ng-app="crmCustomer">` 
`angular.module('crmCustomer', ['customers']);`

sales.html
`<html lang="en" ng-app="crmSales">`
`angular.module('crmSales', ['customers','cart','sales']);`

afterSales.html
`angular.module('crmAfterSales', ['customers', 'remittance']);`
`<html lang="en" ng-app="crmAfterSales">`

Comment: I don't understand why the down vote. Is it unclear or not useful? What can I do to make it better?

Comment: Hey Wrenzi check the following questions which are similar to the one you have asked.These might help you
a) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571301/angularjs-multiple-ng-app-within-a-page
b) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666816/multiple-ng-app-directives-on-a-page
c) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860595/how-to-define-two-angular-apps-modules-in-one-page

Comment: Hi Rao, thanks for your reply. There is a subtle difference between my question and the ones you posted. I am planning to use just one ng-app per HTML but many (about 7) in the whole application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found using multiple apps in one page is burdensome (as you can see in solutions linked by Amruth Rao) and rather creates issues than solves any.

Instead, I create a 'root' app and add the modules I need, ex.:

```
angular.module('crm', ['customers', 'cart', 'sales']);
```

Just make sure the components in those modules have different names, maybe by prefixs.

Comment: Hello Szypelow, thanks for your answer, it's very useful. My idea is almost it, the difference is that I would create one Angular Module for each CRM module, for example: 

`angular.module('crmCustomer', ['customers']);`

customer.html
`<html lang="en" ng-app="crmCustomer">
...
`

`angular.module('crmSales', ['customers','cart','sales']); `

sales.html
`<html lang="en" ng-app="crmSales">
...
`

`angular.module('crmAfterSales', ['customers', 'remittance']); `

afterSales.html
`<html lang="en" ng-app="crmAfterSales">
...
`


Are there any cons to it?

Comment: That's exactly what I did in one of the websites. We haven't got any issues with that so far.