# Slicing an SPA into several components and use AngularJS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm a complete beginner with AngularJS so this may be something completely trivial. I'm building an Asp.net MVC application (really juts delivering insignificant parts) with Web API backend (including login/logout capabilities).

I'd like to use AngularJS in my application. But I have a bit of a dilemma how to slice my page into several sections that somewhat work independently. Let's say this is a simplified skeleton of my page.

[image: Skeleton]

### Questions

How should I structure my AngularJS parts on my page?

1. Should I have a single `ng-app` for the whole page or have several non-nested ones for each individual component on my page?
2. In case of a single `ng-app` I expect to have one `ng-view` that would include *Context* and *Content* components.
3. How about client-side routing with each individual option (single/multi `ng-app`)?

Is this a viable approach or should I think of Angular differently and structure it differently?

I should likely have separate controllers for each individual component and a single authentication service (communicating with Web API on the server) to provide user authorized items.

What would you recommend?

Bare in mind I'm a complete beginner in AngularJS but am very versed in server side part (MVC and API).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try to address some concerns

> Should I have a single ng-app for the whole page or have several
>   non-nested ones for each individual component on my page?

There can be only 1 `ng-app` per SPA, so you cannot have ng-app per component. You can have module per component which can be tied into the `ng-app` related module.

> In case of a single ng-app I expect to have one ng-view that would
>   include Context and Content components.

`ng-view` would only contain the content of the active view. It does not require to have any menus. There can be something like  `RootController` which is container for overall app. The html would consist of the obvious `ng-view` and number of `ng-include`.

Something like

```
<div ng-controller='RootController'>
   <div id="contextMenu"><ng-include  src='contextMenuTemplate'></div>
   <div id="primaryMenu" ><ng-include src='primaryMenuTemplate'></div>
   <div id="secondarMenu" ><ng-include src='secondaryMenuTemplate'></div>
   <div ng-view/>
</div>
```

In your RootController you would have some logic like

```
if ($route.path) {
   $scope.contextMenuTemplate="path1";   //path corresponding to the route
}
```

Or else you can also create a object map and use that for selecting the templates

```
var viewTemplates= [{
    path:"/home",
    contextMenuTemplate:"path1",
    primaryMenuTemplate:"path2",
    secondaryMenuTemplate:"path3"
}]
```

This can now be used for selecting templates in ng-include.

> How about client-side routing with each individual option (single/multi ng-app)?

Routing happens on the `ng-view` part only. You select other templates to load based on the primary view. You can also look at [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) for advance routing stuff.

**Update**
When authentication and authorization comes into picture both the server and client play their part. Server authenticates and then can use that information for service different templates if the user is authenticated or not, and may on the same url. For example `/home/leftnav` can server different content based on the authenticated user. Same can be done on Angular side but this behavior can be by-passed as it is just javascript. Same holds true for api calls (using webapi) where server can decided what to send back.

On client side user state can be tracked using a service\factory. A service like `UserService` with methods\properties like `CurrentUser` can provide details on the current logged in user and can be injected into any directive, filter, controller which as to make decision based whether and what user is logged in..

Comment: **About a single `ng-app`**: You can have several but you have to manually bootstrap them. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18583329/75642)

Comment: OK right, one may be able to do it, but it does not add any value to the solution where similar segregation can be achieved using multiple modules.

Comment: What would you suggest about templates that have authentication/authorization specifics? Would you suggest I create separate templates depending on user state or would it be better to create single templates with logic related to user state? I would rather have several state-related templates that would be less complex and easier to maintain. but what's considered *Angular standard*? Can you add that to your answer? **How to handle user state related to templates and scope?** I expect to set user state on root scope, right?

Comment: @RobertKoritnik i have tried to address your latest issue also.