# How to do multiple views with Angular to support header and sidebar?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-view

I'm using AngularJS for the first time. I've successfully implemented a single `ng-view` in my `index.html` page which contains a `header.html` template. So it looks like below

[image]

But now I'm creating a dashboard (`dashboard.html`). So, I have a left side menu in-addition to `header.html` so it looks like this:

[image]

My index.html is similar to this:

```
<div  ng-include="'templates/header.html'"></div>
<div class="main" id="main-no-space" >
  <div id="main-page">
    <div id="wrapper" class="container">
      <div class='container'>
        <div ng-view></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div  ng-include="'templates/footer.html'">
```

My dashboard.html is similar to this:

```
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
      <li class="active">
        <a ng-href="#/link1">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a ng-href="#/link2">Link 2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a ng-href="#/link3">Link 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/dashboard', {
        templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
        controller: DashboardCtrl
    })
        .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/dashboard'
    });
}]);

function DashboardCtrl() {

}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#main:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
#header {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
#main {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
#sidebar {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}
#content {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    float: right;
    width: 78%;
}
#footer {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular-route.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-include="'header.html'" id="header"></div>
    <div class="main" id="main-no-space">
        <div id="main-page">
            <div id="wrapper" class="container">
                <div class="container">
                    <div ng-view id="main">loading...</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-include="'footer.html'" id="footer"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="dashboard.html">
        <div ng-include="'sidebar.html'" id="sidebar"></div>
        <div id="content">dashboard</div>
    </script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="header.html">
        header
    </script>
     <script type="text/ng-template" id="sidebar.html">
        sidebar
    </script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="footer.html">
        footer
    </script>
</div>
```

**JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mcVfK/928/**

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. but I'm a bit confused. In the fiddle there are no links. In my example there are links in the header and in the side bar. When a link in the sidebar is clicked then the content area will change based on that link while the header still remains as it is.

Comment: I was able to take your fiddle and update it to my needs. http://jsfiddle.net/mcVfK/929/ It works as it is however, to be efficient, how can I avoid including sidebar.html on every sidebar link?

Comment: @birdy oh okay, I misunderstood your question. See this http://jsfiddle.net/mcVfK/933/

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to look at [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) as it allows you to such customization easily.

The second option is to create a leftNav control separate from dashboard and then include it in the index.html. Show and hide it based on the active view.

See one of my old answers [Slicing an SPA into several components and use AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20742510/slicing-an-spa-into-several-components-and-use-angularjs/)

Comment: I see. So `dashboard.html` will be a separate template (similar to `header.html`). How would I show/hide it? I didn't see that in the answer you pointed to

Comment: there could be a `dashboard-leftnav.html`. This would contain view specific to left nav shown with dashboard. The `dashboard.html` would be the main view, that is loaded in ng-view like other views. The area that you have marked `content`

Comment: The problem is that that way I have to include `dashboard-leftnav.html` in `index.html`. But then it will be shown for all pages. I only want it to show when `Dashboard` link gets clicked in the header navigation.

Comment: If you look at my answer. There is a `RootController`. This controller can subscribe to route change and set the correct template by looking at the route. If no template is set, you can hide the left nav using `ng-if`