# Angular JS - Second App and Controller

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get a second AngularJS App and Controller working but it seems the first one runs but the second never does. It seems to work if I make a single app with 2 controllers. Any insights would be appreciated. Thanks!

JS

```
var app1 = angular.module("myapp1", []);
app1.controller('Ctrl1', function($scope){
    $scope.variable = "Ctrl1 Working";
});

var app2 = angular.module("myapp2", []);
app2.controller('Ctrl2', function($scope){
    $scope.variable = "Ctrl2 Working";
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myapp1" ng-controller="Ctrl1">
    <p>{{variable}}</p>
</div>

<div ng-app="myapp2" ng-controller="Ctrl2">
    <p>{{variable}}</p>
</div>
```

JSFiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/paullyvenne/8Ekv5/8/

Comment: you need to bootstrap the second one.  Angular will stop looking for `ng-app`s after it finds the first one.

Comment: this question had been asked / answered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571301/angularjs-multiple-ng-app-within-a-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem here is that AngularJS can't boostrap several applications in just one HTML file.

[Here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp) i let you a link to AngularJS site that explain that.

> Only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML
>   document. The first ngApp found in the document will be used to define
>   the root element to auto-bootstrap as an application. To run multiple
>   applications in an HTML document you must manually bootstrap them
>   using angular.bootstrap instead. AngularJS applications cannot be
>   nested within each other.

Instead of have several `ng-app` that mean several AngularJS Application, you can design a structure of multiples modules organized by feature. If you wanna know about it please see the links below:

[Coderwall](https://coderwall.com/p/y0zkiw)

[clintberry.com](http://clintberry.com/2013/modular-angularjs-application-design/)

[Henriquat.re](http://henriquat.re/modularizing-angularjs/modularizing-angular-applications/modularizing-angular-applications.html)