# bootstrap to use multiple ng-app

Tags: angularjs

I followed the code in [AngularJS Multiple ng-app within a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571301/angularjs-multiple-ng-app-within-a-page)

I don't know what i'm missing.

```
    var reviewApp = angular.module("reviewApp", []);
var reviewApp2 = angular.module("reviewApp2", []);

reviewApp.controller("reviewCtrl",
                     function ShippingAddressCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $scope.name='leo1';
});

reviewApp2.controller("productController",
                     function ProductController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.name1='leo2';
});
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("div2"),['reviewApp2']);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lordango/X3ZsU/1/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you are bootstrapping multiple apps, you can not use `ng-app` attribute more than once, angular takes the first one in markup and bootstraps it automatically, all the other `ng-app`s are ignored and you have to bootstrap them manually

```
var reviewApp = angular.module("reviewApp", []);
var reviewApp2 = angular.module("reviewApp2", []);

reviewApp.controller("reviewCtrl",
                     function ShippingAddressCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $scope.name='leo1';
});

reviewApp2.controller("productController",
                     function ProductController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.name1='leo2';
});
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("div1"),['reviewApp']);
    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("div2"),['reviewApp2']);
});
```

html

```
<div id="div1">
<div ng-controller="reviewCtrl">{{name}}</div>
</div>

<div id="div2">
<div ng-controller="productController">{{name1}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not quite true. You can auto bootstrap one app on a page. I think the problem was the way that angular was added to the head of the document in the fiddle. Your snippet bootstraps on document ready and so gets around the problem in the fiddle.

Comment: I was pointing out that the answer says 'you can not use ng-app attribute' when bootstrapping multiple apps. You can use ng-app once.

Comment: Yes you are right, but I don't think it's a good practice to bootstrap apps in a different place. But I will edit the answer, thanks

Comment: I understand now. bootstrapping is like manually attaching the angular app to a markup. Correct me if I'm wrong but does putting the script in the head fails because the elements have not been created yet and angular tries to bootstrap the app?

Comment: @doodeec in angular.js when does ng-app fire?
when all the scripts have loaded?