# How does inheritance and dependency injection work with angular modules?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm a little confused about how angular modules are intended to work and what would be the best way to use them. I read in a book that services are globally available no matter which module includes them. Filters and directives are obviously also available throughout the template files of the whole app.

A brief example:

```
angular.module('main',[
   'one',
   'two',
   'three'
]);


angular.module('one',[]).service('oneService', ...);
angular.module('two',[
    // angular-module 'one' does not have to be passed here
]).controller(function(oneService){
    // available here
    oneService.do();

});

angular.module('three',[]);


// not a good idea
angular.module('three').service('oneService', ...);
```

Which actually results in a couple of questions for me:

- What is a good way to 'think' about angular modules if there is no real closure?
- Apart from the semantics and the resulting folder structure (which could be done without using modules) - what are the benifits of splitting up one app into different modules?
- Is there any inheritance automagic going on when using a dot-notation for modules, e.g. `angular.module('main')` and `angular.mopdule('main.customers')`?
- Is splitting up an app into different apps (not modules) a possible alternative, e.g. one app per route and if so, what would be a good way to go about it, [as apps cannot contain other apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22548610/can-i-use-one-ng-app-inside-another-one-in-angularjs)?

Answer (score 2):

Miško Hevery discusses it here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&t=34m19s

Then there is the post by Naomi Black:

http://blog.angularjs.org/2014/02/an-angularjs-style-guide-and-best.html

Which references these documents:

https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/angularjs-google-style.html https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XXMvReO8-Awi1EZXAXS4PzDzdNvV6pGcuaF4Q9821Es/pub

Also the latest version of angular documentation [states](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module):

> ... we recommend that you break your application to multiple modules
>   like this:
>
> - A module for each feature
> - A module for each reusable component (especially directives and filters)
> - And an application level module which depends on the above modules and contains any initialization code.

**Summary:**

- modules are just a way to configure the DI subsystem (at least so far)
- if you do want to use modules split your application by *feature*, not by type
- it is actually recommended now to structure your application with one module per feature
- modules do not provide much benefits right now, but they may in the near future when lazy loading for views is implemented

Comment: "modules do not provide much benefits right now, but they may in the near future when lazy loading for views is implemented" this was actually my own feeling about this, nice to hear it from soneone else. Thank you very much for your answer!