# Pass model variable from controller to html using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I am very new to AngularJs. In my example I am trying to read two initiger value from controller model and multiple that numbers in html page by using AngularJs tag.

### controller

```
(function (angular) {
angular.module('Invoice1', [])
.controller('InvoiceController', function () {
    this.qty = 1;
    this.cost = 2;
  });
})
```

### Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
 <title>AngularJs Form Test 2</title>
 <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="invController.js"></script>
</head>
 <body>
  <div id="calculateNumber" ng-app="Invoice1" ng-controller="InvoiceController as invoice">
    <div>
        Quantity : <input type="number" min="0" ng-model="invoice.qty" />
    </div>
    <div>
        Costs : <input type="number" min="0" ng-model="invoice.cost" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <b>Total: </b> {{invoice.qty * invoice.cost | currency}}
    </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I cannot see any multiplication of 'Total'

Comment: line appears in html is as --> Total:  {{invoice.qty * invoice.cost | currency}}

Comment: You have nested `ng-app` attributes, this can cause issues (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22548610/can-i-use-one-ng-app-inside-another-one-in-angularjs)

Comment: Has invController.js been loaded properly and displaying 1 and 2 in your inputs?

Answer (score 2):

You have mentioned multiple `ng-app` in your html.

Use `ng-app="Invoice1"` in `<html>` tag, remove the other one and you are good to go

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="Invoice1">
<head>
 <title>AngularJs Form Test 2</title>
 <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="invController.js"></script>
</head>
 <body>
  <div id="calculateNumber" ng-controller="InvoiceController as invoice">
    <div>
        Quantity : <input type="number" min="0" ng-model="invoice.qty" />
    </div>
    <div>
        Costs : <input type="number" min="0" ng-model="invoice.cost" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <b>Total: </b> {{invoice.qty * invoice.cost | currency}}
    </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Here's the updated [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/yd5VRH8ry4MwnVYbfc44?p=preview)

Comment: I believe you dont have to mension two time ng-app for same module even if you remove ng-app tag from html tag in plunker ... is still works!

Comment: I believe is references issue because I just did another example with javascript and html in same page. i.e. embedded angularjs controller in html and it works

Comment: Yes. keep only one `ng-app`. Be it in `<html>` tag above OR the `<div>` tag. Just be sure that it appears before/with `ng-controller`

Comment: many thanks it works ... I have also answer slighty different ... I have given you mark on your answer...

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to run it by changing controller javaScript code as

```
var myApp2 = angular.module('Invoice1', []);

myApp2.controller('InvoiceController', function ($scope) {
   $scope.qty = 1;
   $scope.cost = 2;
});
```