# Angular JS app in View

Tags: angularjs

How should I proceed when inserting app in a view.

I have a template document the has one app already to control page content. I want to insert other apps in the view. My first app is getting called in the html tag and it is controlling different sections of the page except the view.

Views are another html document that is loaded into a section. Can this other html file contain another app?

I have been trying with include but the app isn't working.

**Exemple** of code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="mid" lang="fr">

<nav ng-controller="navCtrl"></nav>
<main><ng-view><ng-view></main>
<footer ng-controller="navCtrl"></footer>
```

**My view** would contain :

```
<div ng-app="my-second-app" ></div>
<div ng-controller="second-app-Ctrl"></div>
```

Would that work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use one ng-app inside another one in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22548610/can-i-use-one-ng-app-inside-another-one-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 2):

When you include your 'My view' to your example code you are nesting AngularJS applications. You can't include another app as view. AngularJS applications cannot be nested within each other.
take look [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22548610/can-i-use-one-ng-app-inside-another-one-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if you use the manual angular bootstrap function, but I find it hard to believe that this is what you want. You don't need to specify another ngapp in the injected view to let him know he is within angular context, he already knows that, anything below the original ng-app you specified is automatically in angular context. 
Using another angular app within an angular app should only make things complicated and probably unnecessary especially if you are new to angular.
Any way keep it simple , try using the developers guide in http://angular.org , they should give you a sense of how to start.