# nested ng-app Controller proglem

Tags: angularjs

i want to use  ng-app in another ng-app (nested).
and i have controller for each app ,controllers have same name 
code is here :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="/scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/Controller1.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/Controller2.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="MasterApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController as myCtr">
        {{myCtr.testValue}} --->  controler 1
        <div ng-app="DetailApp">
            <div ng-controller="myController as myCtr">
                {{myCtr.testValue}}  ----> controller 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Controlle1.js Code :

```
 var MasterApp = angular.module("MasterApp", ["DetailApp"]);
MasterApp.controller("myController", function ()
 {
    var myCtr = this; 
    myCtr.testValue = " a value from Master App ";
});
```

Controller2.js Code :

```
var DetailApp = angular.module("DetailApp", []);
DetailApp.controller("myController", function () 
{
    var myCtr = this;
    myCtr.testValue = " a value from Detail App ";
});
```

now! controller 2 return value of controller 1!

Result :

a value from Master App 

a value from Master App

this is my problem, any idea?

Comment: Did you try to give a different alias to second controller? Instead of myCtr, try something like myInnerCtr

Comment: yes, when i change the controller name it worked but i wont change it, its in another app!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what angularjs docs says about, so what you try to do is not possible.

> AngularJS applications cannot be nested within each other.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp

But some people found a workaround. Check this post

[Can I use one ng-app inside another one in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22548610/can-i-use-one-ng-app-inside-another-one-in-angularjs)