# Multiple apps and controllers in the same file

Tags: angularjs

In this AngularJS code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
    var app1 = angular.module('app1', []);

    app1.controller('Ctrl1', function ($scope)
    {
      $scope.name = "Jack";
    });

    var app2 = angular.module('app2', []);

    app2.controller('Ctrl2', function ($scope)
    {
      $scope.name = "Steve";
    });

  </script>
  <title>Test Controllers</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-app="app1">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
      <span>{{name}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div ng-app="app2">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl2">
      <span>{{name}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have two ng-app and two controllers. But only the first one seems to work. The name Jack is shown but Steve does not. Why?

Comment: Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DEnB2/

Comment: Your fiddle gives the same result.

Comment: @Jonathan You're wrong. More than one ng-app can be injected. Check out the solution from disperse.

Comment: I've removed my comment so as to not mislead any other readers! Thanks for correcting me AndroidDev and disperse.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The JSFiddle showing the problem is here:  http://jsfiddle.net/DEnB2/

Automatic initialization of a ng-app directive occurs only once but you can manually initialize additional modules using the bootstrapping method.  (See: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap)

The JSFiddle with the solution is here:  http://jsfiddle.net/DEnB2/5/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
    var app1 = angular.module('app1', []);

    app1.controller('Ctrl1', function ($scope)
    {
      $scope.name = "Jack";
    });

    var app2 = angular.module('app2', []);

    app2.controller('Ctrl2', function ($scope)
    {
      $scope.name = "Steve";
    });

    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
      angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('app2'), ['app2']);
    });   
  </script>
  <title>Test Controllers</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-app="app1">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
      <span>{{name}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="app2">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl2">
      <span>{{name}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: An explanation would have been nice too.

Comment: Got pulled away to a meeting, added a brief explanation above.

Comment: Took me about 10 minutes to get it working on my side. I didn't notice the small difference that you made on the second app: <div id="app2"> The id property is used and not the ng-app directive.

Answer (score 0):

According understand only a single standing-ng app. Here's an alternative for you to work on the two controllers. I would like to know why you need two-ng app?

```
<head>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        var app1 = angular.module('app1', []);

        app1.controller('Ctrl1', function ($scope)
        {
            $scope.name = "Jack";
        });

        app1.controller('Ctrl2', function ($scope)
        {
            $scope.name = "Steve";
        });

    </script>
    <title>Test Controllers</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="app1">

    <div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
        <span>{{name}}</span>
    </div>


    <div ng-controller="Ctrl2">
        <span>{{name}}</span>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: I didn't want two controllers under one app. I wanted two apps.

Comment: I think this is a valid approach and the question Luis is asking is: why don't you want to use multiple controllers within a single ng-app directive?