# Multiple controllers in single file using angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am a newbie in angular JS. I am working on controllers.I created the following script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>just learnin!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-ng-app="clock" data-ng-controller="zerocontroller">
        <h2>Readable time is {{timeview.hour}}:{{timeview.min}}:{{timeview.sec}}</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="first" data-ng-app="justin" data-ng-controller="mycontrol">
        <h1>Name is {{k}}</h1>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var just=angular.module('justin',[]);
    just.controller('mycontrol',function($scope){
        $scope.k="Harvey";
    });

    var clock=angular.module('clock',[]);
    clock.controller('zerocontroller',function($scope){
        $scope.time=new Date();
        $scope.timeview={hour:0,min:0,sec:0};
        var update=function(){
        $scope.time=new Date();
        $scope.timeview.hour=$scope.time.getHours();
        $scope.timeview.min=$scope.time.getMinutes();
        $scope.timeview.sec=$scope.time.getSeconds();
        };
        setInterval(function(){$scope.$apply(update)},1000);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the first controller encountered in DOM is only working i.e
the current o/p is:

```
Readable time is 15:55:36

Name is {{k}}
```

But when I interchange this

```
  <div data-ng-app="clock" data-ng-controller="zerocontroller">
        <h2>Readable time is {{timeview.hour}}:{{timeview.min}}:{{timeview.sec}}</h2>
   </div>
```

with this

```
<div class="first" data-ng-app="justin" data-ng-controller="mycontrol">
        <h1>Name is {{k}}</h1>
        </div>
```

the o/p becomes

```
Name is Harvey

Readable time is {{timeview.hour}}:{{timeview.min}}:{{timeview.sec}}
```

I am not able to figure out what is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only define one `ng-app` in a html file. Duplicate `ng-app` declaration is not supported. What you are doing can be achieved by putting ng-app at the `body` or `html` tag such as:
`<body ng-app="app">`
Remove all other ng-app declarations.

Everything can now reside in one module `app`. Or you can create multiple modules and add them as dependency on the root module `app` such as:

```
var just=angular.module('justin',[]);

var clock=angular.module('clock',[]);

var main=angular.module('app', ['justin','clock']);
```

**Update**: As pointed out by @nico, if we want to support multiple ng-app on html, we need to manual bootstrap them using angular.bootstrap API. See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24867578/multiple-apps-and-controllers-in-the-same-file/24867989#24867989) for example.

Comment: I think you're wrong. Multiple app are used in the angular sample page, and this is not a problem if you are using a manual bootstrap, otherwise, only one app on page would work.

Comment: Right i did not think about manual bootstrapping process, that is not so common. I will update my answer.

Comment: @Chandermani can u suggest some book or site to learn this effectively?

Comment: The official documentation, https://egghead.io/ and https://thinkster.io/angulartutorial/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/ will give you a head start. I am too writing book on "AngularJS by Example" but that is still a few months away :).

Answer (score 0):

To complete my comment to the previous response.

You are not allowed to use multiple ng-app in a single page, using automated bootstrap.
BUT. Remove your ng-app (or data-ng-app) from your markup, and start angular apps manually.

It looks like this:

angular.bootstrap('appName', document.getElementById('yourAppBlockId')).

Not sure about the second args, but take a look on the angular documentation will help you.