# Angularjs ng-view does not work

Tags: angularjs, ng-view, angularjs-ng-route

I am trying to create a simple views with `angualrjs + ngRoute`.

Why it doesn't work for me???

Please, can anyone look at my [Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/6evwfxIk0XObaQzQKxcS?p=preview), and explain to me what am I doing wrong?

**my index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Angular Route training</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.5/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.5/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>       
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="main_container">

            <div class="inner" ng-app="app">

                    <div class="container" ng-controller="MainController">
                        <span ng-cloak>{{text}}</span>
                    </div>

            </div>



            <div class="inner" ng-app="views">

                    <h3>Views Menu</h3>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Back to HOME</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#/developers">Our Developers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#/designers">Our Designers</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <div ng-view></div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

**this is app.js:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

var views = angular.module('views', ['ngRoute']);

views.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider.
        when('#/developers', {templateUrl: 'views/dev.html', controller: 'DevCtrl'}).
        when('#/designers',{templateUrl: 'views/design.html',controller: 'DesignCtrl'}).
        otherwise({ redirectTo: 'index.html' });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.text = "Hello World!!!!";
});

views.controller('DevCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.developers = [
        {"name":"John", "family":"Doe"}, 
        {"name":"Anna", "family":"Smith"},
        {"name":"Peter", "family":"Jones"},
        {"name":"Alex", "family":"Volkov"}, 
        {"name":"Yaniv", "family":"Smith"},
    ]
});

views.controller('DesignCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.designers = [
        {"name":"Inna", "family":"Doe"}, 
        {"name":"Anna", "family":"Smith"},
        {"name":"Yafit", "family":"Jones"}
    ]
});
```

**design.html:**

```
<div id="designers" ng-controller="DesignCtrl">

    <h3>Designers List</h3>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Family</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="d in designers">
            <td>{{d.name}}</td>
            <td>{{d.family}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>
```

**and dev.html**

```
<div id="developers" ng-controller="DevCtrl">

    <h3>Developers List</h3>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Family</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="dev in developers">
            <td>{{dev.name}}</td>
            <td>{{dev.family}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>
```

thanks

Comment: All relevant code must be included in your post, instead of linked to. Also - "I'm going crazy" - is hardly a proper description of your problem.

Comment: perhaps this will answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571301/angularjs-multiple-ng-app-within-a-page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is incorrect usage of ng-app. Only declare ng-app once for your application, usually on the html element.

Then declare other modules as dependencies of your main module.

I put the ng-app declaration on the html tag and put your ng-routing in the app module, getting rid of the views module.

http://plnkr.co/edit/btL2QMyHxhDLH7cxZ1YV

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider.
        when('/developers', {templateUrl: 'dev.html', controller: 'DevCtrl'}).
        when('/designers',{templateUrl: 'design.html',controller: 'DesignCtrl'}).
        otherwise({ redirectTo: '/index' });
    // $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

<html ng-app="app">
```

You can also put the view-logic in a separate module, but usually you will then also put it in a different file.

The html5mode is disabled because it triggered an error (it's a little bit tricky to make that work).

Note: it actually is possible to use multiple ng-app by manually bootstrapping them, but you really shouldn't do this unless you have a very good reason for it.

Comment: it doesn't help

here is the [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/6evwfxIk0XObaQzQKxcS?p=preview)

Comment: Yes, of course. Before all I tried it on local machine

Comment: @vol4ikman It does work on plunker. I edited my answer with a link to the fixed code.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem way you declare the dependency within your `app.js` file and also console is complaining  about `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

If you want to declare the separate app you should do something like this

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

var views = angular.module('views', []);

var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute','app','views']);

mainApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider.
        when('/developers', {templateUrl: 'dev.html', controller: 'DevCtrl'}).
        when('/designers',{templateUrl: 'design.html',controller: 'DesignCtrl'}).
        otherwise({ redirectTo: 'index.html' });
    //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

And here is the full working plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/LvPhShkkgTFQsFJ44Ggo?p=preview