# Do multiple apps create multiple rootscopes?

Tags: angularjs, rootscope

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571301/angularjs-multiple-ng-app-within-a-page), it is possible to add multiple apps to the same page. Also it says in the [angularjs documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope) that

> Every application has a single root scope

Then does it stand to reason that there are two rootscopes created if I map two apps to the page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, different apps are completely unrelated to each other, with respect to root scope, modules dependencies, services, directives, injectors

**EDIT**:

To ease your concerns, here's a demo that shows inequality of root scopes between 2 apps. The demo is built roughly as follows:

```
var comparator = {
   set: function(key, obj){
     // set object with some key
   },
   compare: function(key1, key2){
     // console.log of previously-set objects with keys key1 and key2
   }
}

var app1 = angular.module("app1", [])
  .run(function($rootScope){
    comparator.set("rootScope1", $rootScope);
  });

var app2 = angular.module("app2", [])
  .run(function($rootScope){
    comparator.set("rootScope2", $rootScope);
  });
```

[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/joCMU5HNTWFNcO4lQaJ2?p=preview)

Comment: Can you provide a reference link for the same, which explicitly states this ??

Comment: @user96551, not at the moment, but this is the right answer

Comment: @user96551, I've added a demo with rootscopes comparisons to ease your concerns