# Where do JavaScript files go in AngularJS when using Angular Script from Google CDN?

Tags: angularjs

I'm a newbie to AngularJS and don't really understand how setup works when using a script to access AngularJS through Google CDN. I'm having difficulty accessing my JavaScript files.

I am including the script tag

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
```

in my **index.html** file. From my understanding, this basically allows you to "load" AngularJS into your project. Next, I'd like to be able to access the JavaScript files, and so I included another script tag at the end of the body:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
```

My **index.html** looks like

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <title>My Angular App</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
        <div ng-app="myApp">
            <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
                {{ text }}
            </div>
        </div>  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the file path **js/app.js**, I have the following file (from http://toddmotto.com/ultimate-guide-to-learning-angular-js-in-one-day/):

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.text = 'Hello, Angular fanatic.';

}]);
```

Unfortunately, my page is not displaying "Hello, Angular fanatic." Instead, it's just displaying "{{text}}", so it seems that I'm not accessing **js/app.js** correctly. Could someone clarify what I'm doing incorrectly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have two `ng-app` attributes on your page. [Per default there is only one `ng-app` attribute allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571301/angularjs-multiple-ng-app-within-a-page). Just remove the `ng-app` at your `html`-tag, or replace it with `ng-app="myApp"` and remove the one from your div.