# Can't get an Angular App to work inside a MVC Layout

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I got a MVC Site that uses a layout,
in the layout page i use an Angular App, Models and Controllers and everything works like it supposed to, in one of my pages (that is shown inside the layout) i want to use another Angular App & Controller with some really basic functions, you can see the main idea here:
[Plunker for example](http://plnkr.co/edit/bdb4NVi7pzZi1WbU4OYb?p=preview).

Some more info:

- I refer to both of the `.js` files in the layout `<head>` tag:

  ```
  <script src="~/Scripts/AdminVM.js"></script>
  <script src="~/Scripts/ShopVM.js"></script>
  ```
- All the code in my layout page that uses the first App is between two `<div>` tags, first one with `ng-app = "FirstApp"`, second with `ng-controller = "FirstController"`.
- I tried both:

  1. Putting the two `<div>` tags with `ng-app = "SecondApp"`, and `ng-controller = "SecondController"` inside my `.cshtml` file and in between putt my code.
  2. Putting the two `<div>` tags inside my layout page's body and between them putt the `@RenderBody()` tag.

I have no idea what am i doing wrong here, even the most simple thing isn't working:

**ShopVM.js**

```
var app = angular.module("ShopApp", []);
app.controller("ShopViewModel", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.test = "Test123";
});
```

**Shop.cshtml (Not the layout file)**

```
<div ng-app="ShopApp">
    <div ng-controller="ShopViewModel">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Cat1</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Cat2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div>{{test}}</div>

        <input id="Text1" type="text" ng-model="Shop.Test"/>

    </div>
</div>
```

And what i see is a simple test: *{{test}}*

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: open your browser console and see what error you are getting. Your plunker works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in one of my pages (that is shown inside the layout) i want to use another Angular App & Controller

angular does not support nested apps (since you include first one in layout page the second one is nested inside the first one)

Comment: Like i said, I tried it in a non nested way,  with two different  `div` tags that each uses a different app.

Comment: Even if you do that angular will only initialize the first ng-app, it will not run the second one see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571301/angularjs-multiple-ng-app-within-a-page

Comment: So instead of two apps i used one app with two controller, works like char.
Had no idea that even when it's not "Physically" nested it's still called nested apps. Thank you!