# how can i add multiple modules in one page in angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, codeigniter

I am developing web application through PHP using Codeigniter framework.In controller i am loading 2 views as $this->load->view('**menu.html**') & $this->load->view('**home.html**').

In html pages I am using Angularjs framework.As each page have it's own module;but after loading menu.html ,second home.html is not loading properly,as in angularjs there can be only one ng-app.

So how can I add two views on single page using different modules**(For each html i have created separate Module files,means separate javascript files**)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS Multiple ng-app within a page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571301/angularjs-multiple-ng-app-within-a-page)

Comment: Here they used two ng-app in single html page,but i am using two html in pages in single page& I have created separate  modules  for each html page

Comment: Is this used like a single page application, or really multiple views in 1 page?

Comment: multiple views in 1 page

Answer (score 0):

You can manually bootstrap angular on dom element:

```
angular.bootstrap(div1, ['app1']);
angular.bootstrap(div2, ['app2']);
```

Comment: Here initially my **menu.html** file gets loaded,after that **home.html** get loaded,so there are separate html files.

Answer (score 0):

Angular will only bootstrap the first ng-app it encounters. You should only use one app (module) but you can easily create a module that uses the other two modules.

```
angular.module("app", ["yourHomeModule", "yourMenuModule"]);

ng-app="app"
```

Comment: but where i can add ng-app="app",because **2 different html pages are loading**

Comment: means **I am appending home.html to menu.html**

Comment: You could include that in your 'main page' where you load the 2 pages. If this does not work, then please provide an example of your code, or else we can't be of any more help.

Comment: in PHP  cntroller file I have loaded two views as`$this->load->view ( 'menus.html' );
  $this->load->view ( 'index.html' );`<br/>

Comment: In menu.html file<br/>`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.7" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller/menu.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body id='menus'>
<div>
    <div ng-controller="FirstController">
      <p>1: {{ desc }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>`<br/>

Comment: in menu.js file`var firstApp = angular.module('firstApp', []);
    firstApp.controller('FirstController', function($scope) {
      $scope.desc = "First app. ";
    });`

Comment: in home.html<br/>`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.7" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller/home.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body id='index'>
  <div >
    <div ng-controller="SecondController ">
      <p>2: {{ desc }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: in home.js` var secondApp = angular.module('secondApp', []);
    secondApp.controller('SecondController', function($scope) {
      $scope.desc = "Second app. ";
    });
    var dvSecond = document.getElementById('dvSecond');

    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
      angular.bootstrap(dvSecond, ['secondApp']);
    });
    var ex1 = document.getElementById('ex1');
    var ex2 = document.getElementById('ex2');

    angular.element(document).ready(function() {alert();
      angular.bootstrap(ex2, ['secondApp']);
      angular.bootstrap(ex1, ['firstApp']);
    });`