# Can you load the AngularJS Library without it bootstrapping instances of ng-app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to follow this tutorial here: http://www.mattburkedev.com/multiple-angular-versions-on-the-same-page/

It works until I inject my widget into a page that already has includes AngularJS and is using `ng-app` somewhere in the page. Both my version, and the existing version see the 'ng-app' and try to bootstrap it. The result is an error like:

`Uncaught Error: [ng:btstrpd] App Already Bootstrapped with this Element '&lt;div ng-app="myApp" class="ng-scope" ng-controller="IndexController"&gt;'`

So my question is, is it possible to load in my version of Angular I need for my widget, and then tell it to not try and bootstrap anything automatically. I am handling it via:
`angular.bootstrap(angular.element(appDiv), ['myWidget']);`

Answer (score 0):

In [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp) is written:

> only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML document. The first ngApp found in the document will be used to define the root element to auto-bootstrap as an application. To run multiple applications in an HTML document you must manually bootstrap them using angular.bootstrap instead.

So, it is possible, but you didn't provide any code.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571301/angularjs-multiple-ng-app-within-a-page) is the example of two applications on one page.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. My question is whether or not I can load AngularJS WITHOUT it bootstrapping any ngApps found. That way I can load 2 versions of angular, without them both attempting to bootstrap the app and then blowing up.