# Angular JS expressions not evaluating

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've the following simple Angular JS trail, which contains the basic CRUD operations:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>CRUD</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app>
        Simple Expression Evaluator:<br/>
        <input ng-model="calculator"/><br/>
        {{calculator + "=" + $eval(calculator)}}
    </div>
    <h3>CRUD - Comments</h3>
    <div ng-app="commentapp">
      <ul ng-controller="commentController">
        <li ng-repeat="user in users">
          {{user.name}} wrote "{{user.comment}}"
          <br/><a href="#" ng-click="remove(user)">Delete</a>
          <a href="#" ng-click="edit(user)">Edit</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input id="name" ng-model="current.name" value="{{current.name}}" />
          <input id="name" ng-model="current.comment" value="{{current.comment}}" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <button ng-click="save(current)">
            Save
          </button>
          <button ng-click="addNew(current)">
            Add New User
          </button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("commentapp", []);
        app.controller("commentController", function($scope) {
          $scope.users = [{
            "name": "Qwe",
            "comment": "Great!"
          }];
          $scope.current = {};
          $scope.addNew = function(user) {
            $scope.users.push(user);
          };
          $scope.edit = function(user) {
            $scope.current = user;
          };
          $scope.save = function(user) {
            $scope.current = {};
          };
          $scope.remove = function(user) {
            var index = $scope.users.indexOf(user);
            $scope.users.splice(index, 1);
          };
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

However the output shows:

[image]

---

So, the expression evaluator works perfectly, which means Angular JS is tied up correctly. But the rest of the components don't work at all. Instead of `Qwe`, I get the expression `{{user.name}}`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You have 2 `ng-app` tags, Angular cannot support more than one application in a page.

Comment: @Vineet if you want more than one appliaction in a page, you should bootstrap module manually with `angular.bootstrap`. With single app your code works: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CyE2KIgLkOtedW56KLhV?p=preview).
Also, see [this related SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571301/angularjs-multiple-ng-app-within-a-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I tried your script and seem working when I remove the first ng-app

nov the html part is like this

```
<h3>CRUD - Comments</h3>
    <div ng-app="commentapp">
      <ul ng-controller="commentController">
        <li ng-repeat="user in users">
          {{user.name}} wrote "{{user.comment}}"
          <br/><a href="#" ng-click="remove(user)">Delete</a>
          <a href="#" ng-click="edit(user)">Edit</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input id="name" ng-model="current.name" value="{{current.name}}" />
          <input id="name" ng-model="current.comment" value="{{current.comment}}" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <button ng-click="save(current)">
            Save
          </button>
          <button ng-click="addNew(current)">
            Add New User
          </button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jzznuqLs/)

hope this help