# Error with angular program

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angularjs and while trying it I got problem. Here is my code snippet.I defined angular apps named **nameApp** ,**ageApp** and there controllers. First app nameApp is working properly and my problem is with second app ageApp. Its not working properly.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular.js Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var nameApp = angular.module('nameApp',[]);
      nameApp.controller('NameCtrl',function($scope){
        $scope.firstName = "User";
        $scope.lastName = "Name";
      })

      var ageApp  = angular.module('ageApp',[]);
      ageApp.controller('ageCtrl',function($scope){
        $scope.age = "35";
      })      
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="nameApp" ng-controller="NameCtrl">
      First name:<input ng-model="firstName" type="text"/>
      <br>
      Last name:<input ng-model="lastName" type="text"/>
      <br>
      Hello {{firstName}} {{lastName}}
    </div>

    <div ng-app="ageApp" ng-controller="ageCtrl">
      Your Age<input ng-model="age" type="text"/>
      <br>
      My age is:  {{age}}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Values of firstName and lastName are binding properly,but the attribute age is not properly.

Comment: I would recommend you to use single app. currently you've two SPA in your app. rather then making two app, make one app and make a separate modules in same app for both parts.

Comment: @varit05 Can you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571301/angularjs-multiple-ng-app-within-a-page

angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("App2"), ['ageApp']);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can be found by looking at the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp) for **ngApp** directive:

> **Only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML
>   document.** The first ngApp found in the document will be used to define
>   the root element to auto-bootstrap as an application. To run multiple
>   applications in an HTML document you must manually bootstrap them
>   using `angular.bootstrap` instead.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly I have done here is,

I have make two modules name : `nameApp` and `ageApp`. and `nameApp` will be the main module that is having dependency of `ageApp` and will load `ageApp` module as well.

Since Angular is single page application. we can make one main module and inject dependency of other modules.

```html
<html ng-app="nameApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular.js Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var nameApp = angular.module('nameApp',['ageApp']);
      nameApp.controller('NameCtrl',function($scope){
        $scope.firstName = "User";
        $scope.lastName = "Name";
      })

      var ageApp  = angular.module('ageApp',[]);
      ageApp.controller('ageCtrl',function($scope){
        $scope.age = "35";
      })      
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="NameCtrl">
      First name:<input ng-model="firstName" type="text"/>
      <br>
      Last name:<input ng-model="lastName" type="text"/>
      <br>
      Hello {{firstName}} {{lastName}}
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="ageCtrl">
      Your Age<input ng-model="age" type="text"/>
      <br>
      My age is:  {{age}}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps you.

Let me know if you've more questions.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned this is duplicate with;
[AngularJS Multiple ng-app within a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571301/angularjs-multiple-ng-app-within-a-page)

You need to **bootstrap** after **div** is created and it's not obvious in duplicate item.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular.js Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var nameApp = angular.module('nameApp',[]);
      nameApp.controller('NameCtrl',function($scope){
        $scope.firstName = "User";
        $scope.lastName = "Name";
      });

      var ageApp  = angular.module('ageApp',[]);
      ageApp.controller('ageCtrl',function($scope){
        $scope.age = "35";
      });      

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="nameApp" ng-controller="NameCtrl">
      Firsta name:<input ng-model="firstName" type="text"/>
      <br>
      Last name:<input ng-model="lastName" type="text"/>
      <br>
      Hello {{firstName}} {{lastName}}
    </div>

    <div id="App2" ng-app="ageApp" ng-controller="ageCtrl">
      Youra Age<input ng-model="age" type="text"/>
      <br>
      My age is:  {{age}}
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("App2"), ['ageApp']);
  </script>
</html>
```