# Angularjs loading another conttroler from a new file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm trying to seperate my controllers with different files. I looked here and did the following, but I still not able to load the second controller from a new js file. I tried this - [Angularjs Impossible to load multiply ng-apps in one page even with angular.boostrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39194891/angularjs-impossible-to-load-multiply-ng-apps-in-one-page-even-with-angular-boos)

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app="xpCalc">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>RuneScape Toolkit</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="xpCalc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cmbtCalc.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
   <div  ng-controller="xpCalculatorController">
   <p>Insert your current Level  <input type="number" ng-       model="currentLevel"></p>
   <p>Insert your desired Level <input type="number" ng-model="desiredLevel"        ></p>
   <h2>{{xpleft() | number}}</h2>
   </div>

   <br>
   <div  ng-controller="CombatCalculatorController">
<p>Insert your Attack Level  <input type="number" ng-model="ALvl"></p>
<p>Insert your Strength Level  <input type="number" ng-model="SLvl"></p>
<p>Insert your Magic Level  <input type="number" ng-model="MLvl"></p>
<p>Insert your Range Level  <input type="number" ng-model="RLvl"></p>
<p>Insert your HitPoints Level  <input type="number" ng-model="HLvl"></p>
<p>Insert your Defense Level  <input type="number" ng-model="DLvl"></p>
<p>Insert your Prayer Level  <input type="number" ng-model="PLvl"></p>

<h2> {{combatlevel() | number}}  </h2>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS FILE ONE:

```
var app = angular.module('xpCalc', []);

   app.factory('xpService',function(){
  var service = {};


 function calculate(level) {  
    var output = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i < level; i++) {
    output += (Math.floor(i + 300 * Math.pow(2, i / 7)) / 4);
  }
   return output;
   }

 service.getxpLeft = function(currentLevel,desiredLevel){
 var currentXp = calculate(currentLevel);
 var desiredXp = calculate(desiredLevel);

  return desiredXp - currentXp;
     };

      return service;
  });


app.controller('xpCalculatorController', function($scope,xpService) {
    $scope.currentLevel = 1;
     $scope.desiredLevel = 1;

    $scope.xpleft = function() {
      return xpService.getxpLeft($scope.currentLevel,$scope.desiredLevel);
       };
 });
```

SECOND JS FILE:

```
  angular.module('xpCalc').controller('CombatCalculatorController', ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http){
 $scope.ALvl = 1 ;
 $scope.SLvl = 1 ;
 $scope.MLvl = 1 ;
 $scope.RLvl = 1 ;
 $scope.HLvl = 10 ;
 $scope.DLvl = 1 ;
 $scope.PLvl = 1 ;


  }]);
```

Comment: what is ng-app="cmbtCalc", the code you've shown does not include an cmbtCalc, which seems neccessary for this app to work

Comment: @vileRaisin sorry, only one ng per app, I forgot to remove it. But it still won't work

Answer (score 0):

If both files are loaded at the same time, the app variable becomes a global variable, so it is accessible from any js file loaded at the momment. (Be careful with asyncronous)

PD. `angular.module('xpCalc')` may create another module different to app and it may cause you problems

PD. 2: My solution is not tested

Answer (score 0):

i have created a plunkr for your reference.[link](https://plnkr.co/edit/4bEo7u8xavtMKKhUoZU1?p=preview). please check your issue gor resolve.
 please change your second controller like this

```
app.controller('CombatCalculatorController', ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.ALvl = 1;
  $scope.SLvl = 1;
  $scope.MLvl = 1;
  $scope.RLvl = 1;
  $scope.HLvl = 10;
  $scope.DLvl = 1;
  $scope.PLvl = 1;

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine..
Console statement prints perfectly.

```js
var app = angular.module('xpCalc', []);

   app.factory('xpService',function(){
  var service = {};


 function calculate(level) {  
    var output = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i < level; i++) {
    output += (Math.floor(i + 300 * Math.pow(2, i / 7)) / 4);
  }
   return output;
   }

 service.getxpLeft = function(currentLevel,desiredLevel){
 var currentXp = calculate(currentLevel);
 var desiredXp = calculate(desiredLevel);

  return desiredXp - currentXp;
     };

      return service;
  });


app.controller('xpCalculatorController', function($scope,xpService) {
    $scope.currentLevel = 1;
     $scope.desiredLevel = 1;

    $scope.xpleft = function() {
      return xpService.getxpLeft($scope.currentLevel,$scope.desiredLevel);
       };
 });
 angular.module('xpCalc').controller('CombatCalculatorController', ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http){
  console.log('start')
 
 $scope.ALvl = 1 ;
 $scope.SLvl = 1 ;
 $scope.MLvl = 1 ;
 $scope.RLvl = 1 ;
 $scope.HLvl = 10 ;
 $scope.DLvl = 1 ;
 $scope.PLvl = 1 ;
  console.log('end')



  }]);
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app="xpCalc">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>RuneScape Toolkit</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="xpCalc.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cmbtCalc.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
   <div  ng-controller="xpCalculatorController">
   <p>Insert your current Level  <input type="number" ng-model="currentLevel"></p>
   <p>Insert your desired Level <input type="number" ng-model="desiredLevel"        ></p>
   <h2>{{xpleft() | number}}</h2>
   </div>

   <br>
   <div  ng-controller="CombatCalculatorController">
<p>Insert your Attack Level  <input type="number" ng-model="ALvl"></p>
<p>Insert your Strength Level  <input type="number" ng-model="SLvl"></p>
<p>Insert your Magic Level  <input type="number" ng-model="MLvl"></p>
<p>Insert your Range Level  <input type="number" ng-model="RLvl"></p>
<p>Insert your HitPoints Level  <input type="number" ng-model="HLvl"></p>
<p>Insert your Defense Level  <input type="number" ng-model="DLvl"></p>
<p>Insert your Prayer Level  <input type="number" ng-model="PLvl"></p>

<h2> {{combatlevel() | number}}  </h2>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I didn't save as cmbtCalc.js it was only cmbtCalc,