# angularjs 1 manual bootstrap doesnot work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-module

I am new to angularjs.
I tried to create 2 different modules in an single js file and them manually bootstrap one of them to a  element. This was suggested in one of the stackoverflow questions. But this doesnot seem to work.
Both of the modules work fine independently. 
I am not sure what is going wrong here.
Here's my code :-

myApp.js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
var myController = app.controller("ctrl1", function($scope){
"use strict";
$scope.fname = "Bill";
$scope.lname = "Goldberg";
$scope.updatevalue = function () {
    $scope.fullname = $scope.fname + $scope.lname;
    //$scope.fname = "newName"
};
});
app.directive("w3TestDirective", function() {
    "use strict";
    return {
        template : "<h1>This is my life!</h1>"
    };
});

var loginController = angular.module('loginController', []);
loginController.controller('loginCntrl', function ($scope) {
"use strict";
$scope.username="email";
$scope.password="password";
$scope.present = false;
$scope.login = function () {
    "use strict";
    if ($scope.username == "Amar" & $scope.password == "Amar") {
        $scope.present=true;
        $scope.loginMessage = "logged in successfully";
    } else {
        $scope.present=true;
        $scope.loginMessage = "Invalid username or password";
    }
}
});

angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("loginDiv"),['loginController']);
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<!--script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-route.js"></script-->
<script src="scripts/services/myApp.js"></script>
<!--script src="scripts/services/login.js"></script-->
<body>

  <div  id="demoDiv" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl1">
    <span>Values:</span>
    <input type="text" ng-model="fname"/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="lname"/>
    <button ng-click="updatevalue()">fullname</button>
    <br></br>
    {{ fullname }}
    <br></br>
    <w3-test-directive></w3-test-directive>
  </div>
  <br></br>
  <div id="loginDiv" ng-app="loginController" ng-controller="loginCntrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="username"/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="password"/>
    <button ng-click="login()">submit</button>
    <br></br>
    <div ng-if="present"> {{ loginMessage }} </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: An update, the first div with the angular behaviour works i.e. div with id demoDiv works, but the one that is manually bootstrapped doesnot

Comment: It should be specified what 'does not work' means. But likely the problem is that `angular.bootstrap` is executed before page load was completed. It should be also noticed that multiple bootstrapping isn't a common practice and should be used only when the dev knows what he/she's doing very well (in practice it is almost never). The fact that you're 'new to angularjs' suggests that you probably doing it the wrong way.

Comment: My BAD!!!! the binding doesnot work, The 2nd div doesnot show angular behaviour, I get {{ loginMessage }} in the browser. But the first div works well and shows angular behaviour

Comment: Always check the console, the answer is there. Again, in 99,9% of cases there should be a single app instance.

Comment: why are you trying to do it this way?  besides the fact that it is an extremely bad practice to run two angular apps on a single page (and they can't communicate between each other anyway), you can't manually bootstrap angular **and** add `ng-app` (x2!) at the same time, you can only use one or the other.

Comment: also, can you provide the link to the question where someone suggested that you should bootstrap a second app, so I can go downvote it? :)

Comment: I got it from here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571301/angularjs-multiple-ng-app-within-a-page

Comment: I'm not *really* going to downvote that question (though maybe I should), since it was posted in 2013, and this may have been a valid practice with that framework version.  It is usually pretty important to note **when** an answer is posted, since frameworks change so fast, but angular changes ***very*** frequently, so it's a lot more important to not pay attention to answers that are nearly 4 years old.  I posted a proposed solution that should adhere to the modern standards.

Answer (score 0):

This is the completely wrong approach.  You **CAN** have your controllers in more than one module, but you should always have a single module which is the main parent for the app.

Let's Assume `myApp` is your parent module, and make some changes:

First, move the `ng-app` to the body element:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

  <div  id="demoDiv" ng-controller="ctrl1">
...
```

Next, remove `ng-app` from the `loginDiv`:

```
<div id="loginDiv" ng-controller="loginCntrl">
```

Finally, **inject** the `loginController` module into the `myApp` module:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['loginController']);
```

Now, the app will be able to attach both controllers without issue.

http://plnkr.co/edit/rkFY0ASCHaQUTByaHJg3?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue with the following code :-

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['utilModule','loginModule']);
var myController = app.controller("ctrl1", function($scope){
"use strict";
$scope.fname = "Bill";
$scope.lname = "Goldberg";
$scope.updatevalue = function () {
    $scope.fullname = $scope.fname + $scope.lname;
    //$scope.fname = "newName"
};
});
app.directive("w3TestDirective", function() {
    "use strict";
    return {
        template : "<h1>This is my life!</h1>"
    };
});


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<!--script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-route.js"></script-->
<script src="scripts/services/myApp.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services/util.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services/login.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">

  <div  id="demoDiv" ng-controller="ctrl1">
    <span>Values:</span>
    <input type="text" ng-model="fname"/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="lname"/>
    <button ng-click="updatevalue()">fullname</button>
    <br></br>
    {{ fullname }}
    <br></br>
    <div ng-controller="utilCntrl">
      {{ test }}
    <testDirective></testDirective>
    </div>
    <w3-test-directive></w3-test-directive>
  </div>
  <br></br>
  <div id="loginDiv" ng-controller="loginCntrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="username"/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="password"/>
    <button ng-click="login()">submit</button>
    <br></br>
    <div ng-if="present"> {{ loginMessage }} </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

There is only 1 issue, the testDirective tag doesnot print anything on the browser. but that is not a requirement, so I will just ignore this for the time being.
I realize that this is what @Claies has posted. Claies, Thank you very much for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the ng-app directive and angular.bootstrap function to bootstrap you angular application.  You either use ng-app or angular.bootstrap.

If you have two modules "myApp" and "loginController" like you do in your app, you must make "loginController" a dependency of "myApp".  "myApp" will be your angular application module that you can add more dependencies, external or custom.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['loginController', 'ui-router', 'etc'...])
```

Comment: You are right btinoco, I figured this out and wired my application the right way. Thanks for taking the time out to respond to this question.Much appreciated!!!!