# Angular JS only one controller working when i used multiple controllers in a single page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-controller

Problem in handling two controller
As am a learner to angular Js this is where i got my
confusion

I wrote two  with two different apps and controllers and apps
    as I have learnt we can define multiple of these in a single page.

```
The first part div which is

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personCtrl">

    First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
    Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
    <br>
    Full Name: {{fullName()}}

</div>

worked well
```

[image]
When I used with two controllers like this

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personCtrl">

First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{fullName()}}

</div>

<br><br>


<div ng-app="myApp1" ng-controller="personCtrl1">

First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{fullName()}}

</div>


<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
    $scope.fullName = function() {
        return $scope.firstName + " " + $scope.lastName;
    };
});
var app1 = angular.module('myApp1', []);
app1.controller('personCtrl1', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
    $scope.fullName = function() {
        return $scope.firstName + " " + $scope.lastName;
    };
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is what the problem is

[image]

Comment: This might help as well:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571301/angularjs-multiple-ng-app-within-a-page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give an id to your second div and add this line:

```
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("myApp1"), ['myApp1']);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/9952/

Comment: This solved it..Was not aware of angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("myApp1"), ['myApp1']);  thank you

Answer (score 4):

> only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML
>   document. The first ngApp found in the document will be used to define
>   the root element to auto-bootstrap as an application. To run multiple
>   applications in an HTML document you must manually bootstrap them
>   using angular.bootstrap instead.

From https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp

You have two ng-app in your example, put both controllers in the same module (for example myApp) and you'll be fine

Answer (score 1):

This is not the standard practice. You are basically using two application modules on the same page. You should instead have the format as following:

- ng-app

  - ng-controller-1
  - ng-controller-2

I have made the following fiddle for you to review.
https://jsfiddle.net/kaminasw/U3pVM/29864/

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="personCtrl">

    First Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="firstName">
    <br> Last Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="lastName">
    <br>
    <br> Full Name: {{fullName()}}

  </div>

  <br>
  <br>


  <div ng-controller="personCtrl1">

    First Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="firstName">
    <br> Last Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="lastName">
    <br>
    <br> Full Name: {{fullName()}}

  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.firstName = "John";
  $scope.lastName = "Doe";
  $scope.fullName = function() {
    return $scope.firstName + " " + $scope.lastName;
  };
});
app.controller('personCtrl1', function($scope) {
  $scope.firstName = "Jane";
  $scope.lastName = "Doe";
  $scope.fullName = function() {
    return $scope.firstName + " " + $scope.lastName;
  };
});
```

Comment: Sorry about that outdated url. Changed it
https://jsfiddle.net/kaminasw/U3pVM/29864/

Or use the code as it is. The code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should bind the controllers to the same app, and not create seperate apps.

See this Fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/q07scy6k/

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="personCtrl">
        First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
        Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
        <br>
        Full Name: {{fullName()}}
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div ng-controller="personCtrl1">
        First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
        Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
        <br>
        Full Name: {{fullName()}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('personCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.firstName = "John";
        $scope.lastName = "Doe";
        scope.fullName = function () {
            return $scope.firstName + " " + $scope.lastName;
        };
    });

    app.controller('personCtrl1', function ($scope) {
        $scope.firstName = "Jane    ";
        $scope.lastName = "Doe";
        $scope.fullName = function () {
            return $scope.firstName + " " + $scope.lastName;
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use **bootstrapper** to bootstrap the second or third app. Also, this has to be done after it has been defined.

```
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("myApp2"), ['myApp2']);
```

Here is a working example of your code.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script>
  var app1 = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app1.controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "";
    $scope.lastName = "";
    $scope.fullName = function() {
      return $scope.firstName + " " + $scope.lastName;
    }
  });

  var app2 = angular.module('myApp2', []);

  app2.controller('personCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "";
    $scope.lastName = "";
    $scope.fullName = function() {
      return $scope.firstName + $scope.lastName;
    }
  });
</script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="personCtrl" class="col-xs-6">
  First Name:
  <input type="text" ng-model="firstName">
  <br>Last Name:
  <input type="text" ng-model="lastName">
  <br>App 1: Full Name: {{fullName()}}
</div>
<div ng-app="myApp2" ng-controller="personCtrl" id="myApp2" class="col-xs-6">
  First Name:
  <input type="text" ng-model="firstName">
  <br>Last Name:
  <input type="text" ng-model="lastName">
  <br>App 2: Full Name: {{fullName()}}
</div>
<script>
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("myApp2"), ['myApp2']);
</script>
```