# I would like to know why the expression in second div tag is not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <p>Try to change the names.</p>

  <div ng-app="">
    <p>{{5+5}}</p>
  </div>

  <div ng-app="Hullo">
    <p>{{5+5}}</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571301/angularjs-multiple-ng-app-within-a-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work because a page can only have one auto bootstrapping `ng-app` and when it has a value there must be a matching angular module of same name

Comment: This one says you can: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571301/angularjs-multiple-ng-app-within-a-page

Comment: @mplungjan Only one ngApp directive can be auto-bootloaded . There's a difference between 2 apps and 2 `ng-app`'s. I provided a basic and true answer to a very vague and basic question

Comment: So you say only 1 ng-app can be added in a page, right? Also, i wanted to know the difference bw naming and not naming an ng-app directive. it would be great if you can help me out.

Comment: name vs no name is already mentioned in answer....and in docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp

Answer (score 0):

did u setup an angular module named Hullo ? and include that module js into ur Html. basically ng-app is a directive and is typically placed near the root element of the page - e.g. on the  or  tags.

```
    angular.module('hullo',[])
```