# How to run multiple app section on the same page

Tags: angularjs

I have two ng-app but it's not working simultaneously. If I'd comment-out, then the other section is working and vice versa.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <title>Angular</title>
</head>
<body>
    //first section
    <div id = "section1" ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctrl" ng-init="company='Example'; location = 'Earth'">
        <input ng-model="name">
        <h1 ng-bind="name"></h1>
        <h1>Welcome {{name}} to {{company}} at {{location}}</h1>
        <p>{{site}} {{setting}}</p> //running from controller myapp
    </div>
    //second section
    <div id = "section2" ng-app="myapp2" ng-controller="myctrl2"> {{x}} {{y}} </div>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("myapp",[]);
        app.controller("myctrl", function($scope){
            $scope.site  = "www.example.com";
            $scope.setting = "Bliktzgreig";
        });
        var app2 = angular.module("myapp2",[]);
        app2.controller("myctrl2", function($scope){
            $scope.x = "Afforestation";
            $scope.y = "Deforestation";
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Nature
Welcome Nature to Example at Earth
www.example.com Bliktzgreig
Afforestation Deforestation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS Multiple ng-app within a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571301/angularjs-multiple-ng-app-within-a-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ng-app directive is used to auto-bootstrap an AngularJS application. And according to AngularJS Documentation, only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML document. I'd like to quote a section from the documentation here:

`Only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML document. The first ngApp found in the document will be used to define the root element to auto-bootstrap as an application. To run multiple applications in an HTML document you must manually bootstrap them using angular.bootstrap instead. AngularJS applications cannot be nested within each other.`

You can try some alternatives for bootstrap second app http://shrestha-manoj.blogspot.com/2014/06/can-angularjs-have-multiple-ng-app.html

Comment: @sajz do you need more details on it?