# Can two different modules have controllers with the same name in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am making my first app in Angular JS.

I have a three `Tab` Website.

So how should the **angular modules** be defined?
One for each page and one **main** module which controls **all** three page?

I wanted to ask if this is possible?

Comment: Very subjective but probably a controller for anything common to all the tabs and then another controller specific to each tab. Also remember different parts of your DOM can be linked to different instances of the same controller.

Answer (score 3):

You can create three controllers in three different modules under the same name, but if you import the three modules in your main application, a name collision will happen and only the last controller will be available ([Modules and namespace / name collision in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13406791/modules-and-namespace-name-collision-in-angularjs)).

The angular module system makes sense if you want to re-use part of your application in another project or have a real big application with lots of services, filters etc. . Since this is not the case for your small three tabs website, I would suggest to use one module for your app and three different controllers in this module.

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller("tab1", function() {
    })
.controller("tab2", function() {
    })
.controller("tab3", function() {
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are three different pages, you have to make three controllers. 
It's good practice and later you can manage your application properly.

You have to create one module and implement three controllers.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

And then you have to create controllers.

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
   $scope.firstName = "John";
   $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});
```

This is the best structure. Keep this up :)

Comment: Thanks for this! I am planning to use ng-route and implement 3 controllers

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. But it's good practice isolate logic from HTML document as far as possible.

For example.

---

**App.js**

```
app.controller("PanelController", function() {
 this.tab = [youTabId]; // Set a tab by default on load. 

 this.selectTab = function(setTab) {
  this.tab = setTab;
 };

 this.isSelected = function(checkTab) {
  return this.tab === checkTab;
 };
});
```

---

In HTML, on your tab section, add a controller with `ng-controller` like this `ng-controller="PanelController as panel"`.

For each `<li>` add an `ng-class` like this `ng-class="{active : panel.isSelected([yourTabId])}"`.

And for each link `<a>` an `ng-click`, `ng-click="panel.isSelected([youTabId])"`.

By this way, on your `<div>` to show when click on a tab, add an `ng-show="panel.isSelected([yourTabId])"`

---

With this, your code is clean and adaptable.